# Как избавиться от ограничения в 50 мб при обновлении приложения на Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Нашел вот такой гайд - https://medium.com/@johndyer24/creating-and-deploying-an-auto-updating-electron-app-for-mac-and-windows-using-electron-builder-6a3982c0cee6 , сделал всё по инструкции, скрипт проверяет обновление, находит его в GitHub Releases, но при скачивании возникает ошибка - Cannot download differentially, fallback to full download: Error: Maximum allowed size is 50 MB

У многих нашел подобную проблему, но ни одного путного решения не обнаружил

Апдейтер качает новый инсталлятор и при его запуске происходит нормальное обновление, но опять же, его необходимо искать пользователю и запускать самостоятельно, сам скрипт этого сделать не может из за ошибки предоставленной выше

[image: Скриншот папки с файлами, которые качает апдейтер]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему понижением версий electron-updater и electron-builder

"electron-builder": "^20.38.0"
"electron-updater": "^4.0.4"